# Include another template in the application.hbs

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, yeoman

I am using EmberJS with HandleBars and using the Yeoman setup, (but I updated dependencies to the latest).

I have a relatively large application.hbs, and I want to separate it into different files like top-bars.hbs and main-content.hbs and so on, then I want to include them in the application.hbs. but I do not have any views for them, just some separation of the big file, I do not want to make ajax requests for those templates, just want to separate and then include them.

How can I do this in emberJS?

Comment: Try the [`{{render}}`](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-render-code-helper) helper

Comment: `{{render}}` is unlikely to be what your looking for. In its simplest form, anyway, it essentially creates an "island" of controller/view/template (although as usual with Ember all but that template will be auto-generated if necessary). In particular, `{{render}}` will cut off access to the surrounding view and controller. It seems highly likely that you want a partial, which is essentially a lexical include, as @elrick says.

Comment: Partials are described in the Ember Guide at http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/, so if you've gone through that you may already have run into them. If you haven't gone through it (the Ember Guide), then drop everything else you are doing and do it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you maybe looking for is a partial. What you would do is make a partial file in the directory you want most likely somewhere with all the other templates. The resolver complains about either leading underscores or dashes in Yeoman so if one blows up try the other this is mostly for a visual indication when looking through your files which ones are partials. So make `_top-bars.hbs` and put the code you want in there. and the in the `application.hbs` just do `{{partial "top-bars"}} and it will put the template into the application template without changing the scope.

Comment: and this is not ajax ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with ajax, controllers, views, models, or anything else related to Ember or Ember Data. Partials are simply a way to split off some templating code and keep it over in a separate file and then bring in back and plonk it into a template (or more than one template) when you need it.

Comment: No sir nothing to do with Ajax. It's just a ember mechanism you can use to make a partial. Ember will look for the template and just put it in place no Ajax calls.